# Sum together different subsets in a vector without a for loop in R

Tags: r, vector, sequence

Suppose I have the vector

```
v = 0:12
```

Is it possible to create a new vector which sums different subsets of that vector v together without using a for loop? For example:

Suppose I wanted to sum the first 1 elements together, then the next 2 elements, then the next 3 elements, then the next 4 elements. Then you would end up with vector:

```
0 3 12 21 42
```

Can this be done without a for loop? I am not sure.

Comment: How did you get 21 and 42?

Answer (score 1):

You can try `by` to make vector values grouped and summed

```
> n <- ceiling(sqrt(2 * length(v)))

> c(by(v, head(rep(1:n, 1:n), length(v)), sum))
 1  2  3  4  5
 0  3 12 30 33
```

Answer (score -1):

```
> n=4;l=n*(n+1)/2;v=0:(l-1)
> sapply(split(v,rep(1:n,1:n)),sum)
 1  2  3  4
 0  3 12 30
```

Or if the length of the vector is not `n*(n+1)/2`:

```
> v=0:12
> l=length(v)
> n=ceiling((sqrt(8*l+1)-1)/2)
> r=head(rep(1:n,1:n),l)
> sapply(split(v,r),sum)
 1  2  3  4  5
 0  3 12 30 33
> tapply(v,r,sum)
 1  2  3  4  5
 0  3 12 30 33
```

The second argument for `tapply` is automatically converted to a factor:

```
tapply                  package:base                   R Documentation

Apply a Function Over a Ragged Array

Description:

     Apply a function to each cell of a ragged array, that is to each
     (non-empty) group of values given by a unique combination of the
     levels of certain factors.

Usage:

     tapply(X, INDEX, FUN = NULL, ..., default = NA, simplify = TRUE)

Arguments:

       X: an R object for which a split method exists.  Typically
          vector-like, allowing subsetting with [.

   INDEX: a list of one or more factors, each of same length as
          ‘X’.  The elements are coerced to factors by as.factor.
```

I derived the value of `n` by using the quadratic formula:

```
l=n*(n-1)/2
2*l=n^2-n
n^2-n-2*l=0
n=(--1±sqrt((-1)^2-4*1*-2*l))/2*-1
n=(1±sqrt(1+8*l))/-2
n=(1-sqrt(1+8*l))/-2
n=(sqrt(1+8*l)-1)/2
```

`n*(n-1)/2` is the same as `sum(1:(n-1))` and `choose(n,2)` and `length(which(lower.tri(matrix(,n,n))))`.